# Polidea ios-class-guard is DEAD in XCode 7, replace it or fix it?

Tags: ios, obfuscation, xcode7

Everything is great before XCode 7 and iOS 9. After we upgrade XCode to 7.0 and 7.0.1, the ios-class-guard keep annoying us. 
You can't install ios-class-guard based on the official tutorial. The homebrew is failed to install formula.

```
The following build commands failed:
CompileC /Users/Digiflex/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios-class-guard-afpnixzupjudctebfxyqptpmbgpa/Build/Intermediates/ios-class-guard.build/Release/MachObjC.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CDLCSegment.o Source/CDLCSegment.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)
```

Then, we download source code from [Polidea/ios-class-guard](https://github.com/Polidea/ios-class-guard). After we fixed couple bugs, and compiled it. We archived build and export to

```
/usr/bin/ios-class-guard
```

When we do the obfuscation, it looks OK. But when we run project in XCode 7, we got many errors like:

```
Unexpected '@' in program
```

or

```
Missing context for method declaration
```

After many hours research with no conclusion, our question are:

1. How to fix the ios-class-guard problem by myself, under XCode 7 environment?
2. Is there any other open source project provide a similar feature, which is can obfuscate Class, Method and String?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is new version (0.8) of `iOS Class Guard` with Xcode 7 support.

Answer (score 0):

I succeeded to fix errors like this by replacing

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
```

with:

```
@import UIKit;
```

In my project .pch file.
Then I also changed in my project build settings:

Enable modules (C and objective C) to YES

**However** I end up having the same problem for imports of classes in the .pch file:

```
    #import "BDError.h"
```

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of iOS Class Guard (0.8, as of this writing) still has issues with Xcode 7.3, and didn't fully fix support for prior versions of Xcode 7.

> 1. How to fix the ios-class-guard problem by myself, under XCode 7 environment?

Starting with Xcode 7, the iPhoneOS SDK that ships with Xcode does not include the ARM-based .dylib dynamic-library files anymore, and these have been replaced .tdb files.  The .tbd files appear to be markup (text) files describing their corresponding .dylib files, specifically including at least some of the symbols. The errors you see are because of this change.

The consequence of this is that in order to obfuscate an ARM-based build, the symbols to exclude can only be found by examining the iPhone simulator libraries.  Currently, this implies that an x86/x86_64 build must be created for the analyze phase of building.

According to "[apple staff](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/9176#9176)":

> "For those who are curious, the .tbd files are new 'text-based stub libraries', that provide a much more compact version of the stub libraries for use in the SDK, and help to significantly reduce its download size."

These .tbd files do not contain all the necessary symbols, for automatically finding excludes, though.

iOS Class Guard 0.8 fixed the error messages, but in such a way that it wasn't finding all the symbols that should be excluded.

> 2. Is there any other open source project provide a similar feature, which is can obfuscate Class, Method and String?

Yes, [PPiOS-Rename](https://github.com/preemptive/PPiOS-Rename) is a fork of ios-class-guard that fixes this issue, by always searching for symbols in the iPhoneSimulator SDK, even if the build was compiled for a device. It has also been updated to work with Xcode 7.3. (Full disclosure: I work for [PreEmptive Solutions](https://www.preemptive.com/) who created this fork, but it is open source and free.)